# Árvore Binária retornando vazia em pesquisa

Tags: c, c++, busca-binária

No meu menu ele não esta fazendo a saída correta na impressão. Além da pesquisa retornar apenas árvore vazia.

```
#include<iostream>
#include<string>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<stdio.h>
using namespace std;

typedef int TipoChave;

typedef struct TipoRegistro{
    TipoChave Chave;
    string Nome;
    float Preco;
    int QuantEstoque;
}TipoRegistro;

typedef struct TipoNo* Apontador;

typedef struct TipoNo{
    TipoRegistro Reg;
    Apontador Esq, Dir;
}TipoNo;


void ImprimeEmOrdem(TipoNo *pRaiz)
{
    if(pRaiz != NULL)
    {
        ImprimeEmOrdem(pRaiz->Esq);
        cout<<"IMPRIME  "<<pRaiz->Reg.Chave;
        ImprimeEmOrdem(pRaiz->Dir);
    }
}

void Pesquisa(TipoRegistro x, Apontador *p)
{
    if((*p) == NULL)
    {
        cout<<"ERRO 1: Regristo nao esta presente\n"<<endl;
    }

    if(x.Chave < (*p)->Reg.Chave)
    {
        Pesquisa(x, &((*p)->Esq));
    }
    if(x.Chave > (*p)->Reg.Chave)
    {
        Pesquisa(x, &((*p)->Dir));
    }
    else
    {
        x = (*p)->Reg;
    }
}

void Insere(TipoRegistro x, Apontador *p)
{
    cout << "teste";
    if(*p == NULL)
    {
        cout << "primeiro if";
        *p = (Apontador)malloc(sizeof(TipoNo));
        (*p)->Reg = x;
        (*p)->Esq = NULL;
        (*p)->Dir = NULL;
        cout << "Registro inserido com sucesso";
    }

    if(x.Chave < (*p)->Reg.Chave)
    {
        cout << "segundo if";
        Insere(x,&(*p)->Esq);
        return;
    }

    if(x.Chave > (*p)->Reg.Chave)
    {
        cout << "terceiro if";
        Insere(x, &(*p)->Dir);
        return;
    }

    //else cout<<"ERRO 2 : Regristo ja existe na arvore\n";
}

void Inicializa(Apontador p) //Apontador 'e um ponteiro
{
    p = NULL;
}

int main()
{
    int op, c = 1;
    Apontador No, Topo;
    TipoRegistro x;

    Topo = NULL;

    //No = Topo;

    do      //while(c != 0)
    {
        cout<<"Escolha Uma das opcoes abaixo"<<endl;
        cout<<"\t1. Inserir Produtos:  \n\t2. Buscar Produtos \n\t3. SAIR"<<endl;
        cin>>op;


        switch (op)
        {

            case 1 :
                cout<<"DIGITE O CODIGO : ";
                cin>>x.Chave;
                cout<<"DIGITE O NOME DO PRODUTO : ";
                cin>>x.Nome;
                cout<<"DIGITE O PRECO DO PRODUTO : ";
                cin>>x.Preco;
                cout<<"DIGITE A QUANTIDADE DISPONIVEL NO ESTOQUE : ";
                cin>>x.QuantEstoque;

                cout << x.Chave << endl;
                cout << (Topo == NULL) << endl;

                Insere(x, &Topo);

                cout << Topo->Reg.Chave;


                Pesquisa(x, &Topo);

                break;

            case 2 :
                cout<<"DIGITE O CODIGO OU NOME A SER BUSCADO : ";
                cin>>x.Chave;
                Pesquisa(x, &Topo);
                break;

            case 3 :
                cout<<"VOCE ESTA SAINDO\n";
                c = 0 ;
                break;

            default :
                cout<<"OPCAO INVALIDA";
                break;
        }

    }while(op !=3 );

    ImprimeEmOrdem(Topo);
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Inicialização**

Primeiro, a função `Inicializa(No)` atribui o valor `null` para a variável passada por parâmetro. Porém, esta é um argumento apenas de entrada, e portanto o valor não é refletido para fora do escopo da função.

Assim sendo, a variável `No` antes da função possui lixo de memória, e após a função continua possuindo lixo de memória. Para corrigir isso, deve-se transformar o parâmetro `p` da função em um parâmetro de entrada e saída. Isso pode ser feito de dois modos (o primeiro pode ser utilizado em C ou C++, mas o segundo recomenda-se que seja utilizado apenas em C++):

*C/C++:*

```
void Inicializa(Apontador *p) {
    *p = NULL;
}
```

*C++:*

```
void Inicializa(Apontador &p) {
    p = NULL;
}
```

Assim, a chamada `Inicializa(No)`, irá corretamente inicializar o valor da variável `No`.

O segundo problema de inicialização no seu código é na linha `if ( c = 1 ) Topo = No;`. O significado desta linha para o compilador é:

1. Atribuir `1` à variável `c`;
2. Verificar se `c` é verdadeiro;
3. Atribuir `No` a `Topo`.

Pelo passo **1**, o passo **2** será avaliado como verdadeiro sempre, e portanto em toda iteração do seu looping, será feita atribuição de `No` a  `Topo`. Portanto:

```
if ( c = 1 ) Topo = No;
```

Faz o mesmo que simplesmente:

```
Topo = No;
```

A variável `c` não é utilizada em nenhum outro lugar do seu código. Acredito que este não seja o seu objetivo. Caso ele o seja, como pode notar, pode-se removê-la sem problemas semânticos e lógicos.

**Inserção**

Considero que pelo menos o primeiro erro de inicialização foi corrigido.

Após fazer a leitura do valor a ser inserido na sua árvore, você chama o comando `Insere` passando o valor lido `x.Chave` e a variável `Topo`. Ela sofre do mesmo problema que a função `Inicializa`:

A variável `Topo` é passada no parâmetro `p` apenas como argumento de entrada, e por isso todas as alterações feitas nela dentro da função `Insere` não são refletidas fora do seu escopo.

A correção pode ser feita do mesmo modo que a função `Inicializa`, e irá ficar como exercício a correção (ela é um poquinho mais chata, uma vez que a variável `p` é utilizada em chamadas recursivas; porém a lógica é a mesma, e é um ótimo exercício sobre ponteiros).

Aparentemente, estas são as correções que respondem sua questão.

**Observação**

Na explicação sobre a transformação do parâmetro `p` na função `Inicializa` em um parâmetro de entrada e saída, cabe um pouco de discussão sobre qual dos dois métodos devem ser utilizados, uma vez que tanto através de um poniteiro quanto através de uma referência, pode-se realizar a passagem do parâmetro como sendo de entrada e saída.

Em todo o caso, não vou me atentar sobre isto pois esta é uma questão sobre boas práticas, e amplamente aberta à opiniões. Por isso, coloquei os dois métodos e não sugeri nenhum deles.

Comment: Vinicius, depois que você me falou sobre estes erros eu fiz as mudanças, mas a insere continua saindo do terminal, nisso decidir compilar no terminal usando G++, e o arquivo gerado da falha de segmentação falando que não pode gravar na memoria.
Não sei porque esta acontecendo isso. 

Caso possa me ajudar...

Comment: Claro, posso sim! Atualize seu código aqui no post, pra eu saber como ficou.

Comment: Em qual linha esta ocorrendo o erro?

Comment: No meu computador ele esta inserindo corretamente  porem quando tem que volta no menu, ele da segmentation fault.


Depois desistir deste codigo e fiz outro bem mais completo e eficiente. Obrigado Vinicius. Irei atualizar este.